# Greatest hits? Can I find the most \ref'd part of my document?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I now have a 200 page document and have used `\ref` and `\label` very frequently. 
I was wondering if it is possible to use LaTeX to create a table at the start of the document with the "top ten" most internally referenced sections/figures/tables/pages of the document? 
This would be interesting for me as author but also hopefully interesting for the reader also - e.g. identifying the key parts of the document to read.

No idea if LaTeX is able to do this or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is an already made solution with LaTeX for this.
If you are using linux, usual command line utilities can be used for that. 
For example:

**EDIT**

sort the output of the pipe:

```
  grep -o ref\{[[:graph:]]*\} file.tex | sort |uniq -c | sort -nr
```

**Original answer**

```
  grep -o ref\{[[:graph:]]*\} file.tex | sort |uniq -c
```

gives the following output in a small tex file:

```
      2 ref{fig:constant-equipartition}
      1 ref{fig:current-match}
      1 ref{fig:hoffman-currents}
      1 ref{fig:hoffman-ratios}
      2 ref{fig:phase-advance}
      1 ref{fig:phase-law}
```

Comment: any answer that gets a grep pipeline onto tex.sx must be worth a vote or two:-) (you could add another (numeric) sort to the end to make the list be in order of most used first.)

Comment: Thanks for this, i'd still love to see it done in tex though ;)